# AutoLayout contraints - cannot resize height

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, xcode7

I'm struggling a bit with the auto layout constraints in a super simple test view.
For test I added a label, want it x number of pixels from left side, and 5 pixels from top, right, bottom.
When I do this and do an update frame, the view collapse to the min height, and when I insert the view into a tab, the main window collapses and I cannot resize the height.

I can understand why the view collapses to min height, but why does the main window collapse, and why can't I adjust the height.

Which is the missing / wrong constraints.

Thanks

**Edit**: Noticed I by mistake used a TextField instead of a Label which could have explained the fixed height, but even after changing to a label I see the same issue. If I instead set the height to fixed, so the constraints are left, top, right, height, then I can resize the window as expected, but obviously the label doesn't resize its height.

[image: setting in IB]
[image: Main window collapses, and height cannot be changed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label's content-hugging priorities are presumably greater than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut` (500). That tells the auto layout system to prefer to resize the window rather than stretch the label beyond the size required by its contents.

Reduce that priority.

Comment: Bingo, setting the label priority to low fixed the issue. Thank you very much for you help